# JAVA EWS: setExtendedProperty with MapiPropertyType.Binary

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have to enhance an existing JAVA app to store deadlines into several calendar all owned (created) by the same Shared-Mailbox.

Synchronisation of the deadlines in the app and the outlook calendars is no problem.

Apart from syncing the dates the JAVA app should be able to send invitations to the specific calendar. I have used the description https://willcode4foodblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/understanding-sharing-invitation-requests-ews-managed-api-1-2-part-1/. I needed to port that stuff from c# to JAVA. On sendAndSaveMessage I always receive this Exception:

```
exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:74)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:158)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.sendItem(ExchangeService.java:789)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage.internalSend(EmailMessage.java:156)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage.sendAndSaveCopy(EmailMessage.java:300)
```

Using the debugger I found out, that all Extended Properties of MapiPropertyType.Binare have a null value. That's eg.

```
byte[] binInitiatorEntryId = hexStringToByteArray(initiatorEntryID);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition pidLidSharingInitiatorEntryId = 
  new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(propertySetSharing, 0x8A09, MapiPropertyType.Binary);           
invitationRequest.setExtendedProperty(pidLidSharingInitiatorEntryId, binInitiatorEntryId);
```

So in the debugger the extended property exists, but the value is "null".

All other fields that are noted in the example look ok in the debugger. It's just that the binaries are all "null". I also compared the sharing_metadata.xml attachment with one created by Outlook and they are identical. Ok, there are a few fields I got to play with (let's say: do I have to use a "special folder" for pidLidSharingFlavor because I didn't find any explanations in the specs on what is a special folder). But since it is obvious that a "null" value for MapiPropertyType.Binary is not correct it does not make any sense to check other possibilities.

So mainly there are two questions regarding this issue which I hope someone with a bit more experience could explain:

**Question 1:** Is there any special way in JAVA to store Extended Properties of MapiPropertyType.Binary?

**Question 2:** Is there any way to get more information on the "internal server error occured" from EWS? Even enhancing the trace does not give any more information beside the XML representation of the message.

Thanks in advance.

ChriS